# PHP allow_url_fopen is required

Tags: php, wordpress

How to resolve this issue?

> PHP allow_url_fopen is required

`allow_url_fopen=on` is already mention in the `php.ini` file.

here is the image which shows the error.

[image]

Comment: Verify the setting with `phpinfo()`.  Restart the web server or PHP process after updating php.ini.

Comment: Also use phpinfo() to determine that the INI file you're looking at is the same one PHP is using ...

Comment: tried many times, but facing the same issue @Devon

Comment: yes it is the same INI file @Kevin_Kinsey

Comment: @WaqasMarwat what did you try?  What does phpinfo() say?  If it's on, then it's an issue with your application.

Comment: @Devon allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
max_file_uploads = 20
i restart local server then every thing were working properly but on webhost it is not working. kindly guide me what to do.

Comment: I can't guide you, if phpinfo() on the web host reports allow_url_fopen on but your application doesn't recognize it, it is a bug, and you need to review the application or contact the developer.

Comment: have any body checked the image i have attached, as i am thinking its not about ON or OFF rather it is showing REQUIRED. which might be issue of something else

Comment: If you don't know what that means, this isn't the right site for you.  This isn't tech support for application installs, this is a programmer resource...

Comment: @WaqasMarwat maybe your host uses separated pools for each domain with different PHP configuration other than the main `php.ini`. But if you see it `on` when you're calling `phpinfo()`, then there is a bug in the app code for sure.

Comment: You've tagged this with the phpMyAdmin tag, but this doesn't look like any page that phpMyAdmin displays. You've also tagged WordPress, so I imagine it comes from WP, but I'm not an expert there so I'm not completely sure.